# Show title instead of id in edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, model-associations

Say I got some lists and some tasks. Each list can have many tasks, a task belongs to a list. When I editing one of the tasks rails is showing the id of the corresponding list in the inputfield.

How is it possible to show the title of the list instead of the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a `select` input, something similar to this in your form code:

```
<%= f.select :list_id, List.all.collect { |l| [l.name, l.id] } %>
```

This will display the `name` of each `List`, but will actually assign the `id` to the task's `list_id`

Comment: Thanks! Good idea but it is a good way (or part of the rails convention) to run a request against the database at this point?

Comment: You could do something like `@lists = List.all` in your controller and do `@lists.collect { ... }` instead, but Rails' own documentation has an example just like this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select